# Facebook comments box plugin suddently not working in IE11

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-11, facebook-comments

I have used the Facebook comments boxes on most of the pages on my website for about a year. 
It works fine in Firefox - my preferred browser.
I am quite sure I must have checked it in MS-IE back then. I don't remember the last time I checked it in MS-IE, but now it doesn't work anymore. It has disappeared.
A few months ago I added jQuery to my pages, to be able to add 'tabindex="1"' in the following way: (<)div id="outer" tabindex="1"(>)
I am pretty sure I must have checked it again in MS-IE too, but in any case I have just created a test-page where I removed it here: 
http://www.transformation.dk/index-dan-test.html 
But that didn't make any difference. It is still not showing up in MS-IE11.
Is there a current incompatibility between IE11 and the fb comments box?

I hope someone can help.

Henrik

Sept. 18, 2014: 
The above problem is on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. Now I have tried reinstalling MS-EI11 and deleting the browser cache. But that didn't help.
BUT on my Win 7 32-bit machine the facebook comments box plugin DOES work!

Answer (score 0):

I am just discovering the exact same problem.  Same IE version, same machine, too.  It really did seem to work last week or so.

The Facebook feed box works in Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

My comment is probably not directly helpful to you, but perhaps builds more evidence that it is not just YOU, right?